# VHDL Multidimensional arrays with different internal size

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, modelsim

I'm wondering if it is possible or not to create bi-dimensional arrays having different inner sizes. 
For example I can create

```
type type1 is array(0 to N-1) of std_logic;
type type2 is array(0 to M-1) of type1;
signal mysig : type2;
```

with `N` and `M` that are generics or constants defined in a package. In this case I would have a vector of M elements, where each one is a vector of N elements.

Now assume that for me `N` is not fixed but it passed to the entity as an array of integers, so that for each `M` I have a different vector size. Is there a smart way to code this situation using arrays?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll have to provide a much more concrete example of what you mean. This sort of construct makes sense in a software system where memory can be dynamically allocated and data is processed sequentially. But where would such a thing be used when describing *hardware*?

Comment: @DaveTweed let's suppose that I have a component having `M` interfaces, and each interface can have `N` ports that are the real connections with the external. In principle, each interface can have a different number of internal ports.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not following. How would such an array be useful in communicating/connecting with those MxN ports? And how would you specify the value of N for each M? There are ways to do what you're describing, but they don't involve such an array.

Comment: @DaveTweed It would be useful for example to connect a `ready` signal from the input [interfaceI][portY] to the output [interfaceX][portZ]. I know that there are other ways, I was just wondering if it possible to use arrays to achieve it.

Comment: type2 isn't a multidimensional array. It's a single dimensional array that happens to have a single dimensional array element type. The type2 declaration has only one index subtype definition. IEEE Std 1076-2008 5.3.2.1 para 4 "An array object is characterized by the number of indices (the dimensionality of the array); the type, position, and range of each index; and the type and possible constraints of the elements. ..."

Comment: @user8352 you are right I'm sorry, but still the question remains the same...is it possible to have multidimensional arrays (or single dimensional arrays of arrays of...) with internal different sizes?

Comment: It's not possible to have "ragged arrays" in VHDL. So each element in an array must have the same size. VHDL-2008 allows unconstrained and partially constrained arrays (that not the same as ragged arrays). Ragged arrays can be emulated: see [vhdl port declaration with different sizes](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/312904/vhdl-port-declaration-with-different-sizes/312924#312924)

Comment: No. para 5 above ref. "A one-dimensional array has a distinct element for each possible index value. A multidimensional array has a distinct element for each possible sequence of index values that can be formed by selecting one value for each index (in the given order). The possible values for a given index are all the values that belong to the corresponding range; this range of values is called the *index range*."

Comment: @Paebbels you mean "[jagged arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array)" ;)

Comment: @JHBonarius No "ragged". (Some say jagged) but most translations use ragged like in "ragged left" (see LaTeX) or "ragged alignment".

Comment: @Paebbels OK learned something today. Never saw the word 'ragged' being used in the C/C++/C# scene though. Microsoft also uses 'jagged' in their language documentation for instance.