# Emulation of ragged array in vhdl

Tags: vhdl

What I want to achieve is something similar to the following entity. Now I want data_(x)_i to be an array of std_logic_vector, with each individual length definable at component instantiation.

```
entity module_A is
    port(
        rst_i      : in  std_logic;
        clk_i      : in  std_logic;
        data_0_i   : in  std_logic_vector( 1 DOWNTO 0);
        data_1_i   : in  std_logic_vector( 2 DOWNTO 0);
        data_2_i   : in  std_logic_vector( 3 DOWNTO 0);
        data_3_i   : in  std_logic_vector( 4 DOWNTO 0)
    );
end entity module_A;
```

I tried the following code

#### utils.vhd:

```
package utils is
    type int_array_t is array (integer range <>) of integer;
    type data_array_t is array (integer range <>) of std_logic_vector;

    function get_width (
        int_array: int_array_t   
    ) return integer;

end package utils

package body utils is
    function get_width(
        int_array: int_array_t
    ) return integer is
    begin
        for i in 0 to int_array'length-1 loop
            return int_array(i);
        end loop;
    end function;
end package body;
```

#### module_A.vhd:

```
entity module_A is
    generic(
        DATA_WIDTH : int_array_t := (2, 3, 4, 5)
    );
    port(
        rst_i  : in  std_logic;
        clk_i  : in  std_logic;
        data_i : in data_array_t(DATA_WIDTH'range)(get_width(DATA_WIDTH)-1 DOWNTO 0)
    );
end entity module_A;
```

Modelsim throws the following error

> ** Error: D:/WORKSPACE/PERSO/HPD_ALT/RTL/RTL/pkg_utils.vhd(24): Parameter for attribute "left" must be locally static.

Is there a way to achieve what I want?

Comment: An integer vector type is already defined in VHDL-2008 as `integer_vector`. What tool are you using?

Comment: I am using Modelsim. I noticed about integer_vector (I am reading again [your answer in this post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/312904/vhdl-port-declaration-with-different-sizes) to check if this can apply to my problem).

Comment: Your `get_width` implementation is wrong. It always returns `int_array(0)`. My proposed solution linearizes the differently sized vectors into one long vector. The function `low` and `high` are used to calculate the boundaries of the i-th embedded vector.

Comment: Add a begin to the function body, context clauses and an architecture your code analyzes and elaborates (-2008), due to the function returning the first value of DATA_WIDTH. See IEEE Std 1076-2008 5.3.2 Array types *An array object is a composite object consisting of elements that have the same subtype* (subtype meaning index constraint in an array type element). Your data_i declaration would not meet that criteria if ragged element widths were possible using get_width (which it is not).

Comment: @user8352, I am sorry, my (poor) English does not let me tell for sure if there is a workaround to my problem at all, based on your answer.
I corrected the begin in the function body; I am not sure I understand the part about the contexts clauses and the architecture. Are you still referring to the function / package?